# get sku in order grid by joining 2 tables Magento

Tags: magento, join, grid

Hi i need to show the product skus in the order grid and for that i have added a following query

```
$collection->getSelect()->join('sales_flat_order_item', 'sales_flat_order.entity_id = sales_flat_order_item.order_id',array('sku'=>'sku'));
```

in the

_prepareCollection()

but this gives me the following error

```
Item (Mage_Sales_Model_Order) with the same id "1537254" already exist
```

please suggest me where i am doint the mistake or how can i get this.thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code for product sku

```
 $collection->getSelect()->joinLeft('sales_flat_order_item', 'sales_flat_order_item.order_id = main_table.entity_id', array('skus' => new Zend_Db_Expr('group_concat(sales_flat_order_item.sku SEPARATOR ", ")')));

$collection->getSelect()->group('main_table.entity_id');
```

add column in grid.php file

```
        $this->addColumn("skus", array(
        "header" => Mage::helper("catalog")->__("SKU"),
        "index" => "skus",
       ));
```

Comment: HI this works fine but it has made  order grid takes lot of time in loading.I have lot of orders around 1 lakh.

Comment: how many rows you display it will take time based on it. total rows does not make difference for loading. So there may be you need to check other part of code.